# Is it possible to only have one gh-pages repo?

Tags: github, github-pages

Last year I have been working on a project, that required gh-pages. Everything was totally fine and hosted on Github Pages. Today I started to work on another project, that will also require gh-pages. However when I started pushing local repo to github, I realized something. Somehow this newly created react app already had a remote origin with a link to that first last-year repo. How is it possible? Will my first repo stop working if I use gh-pages with this new project?

Comment: You are only allowed one GitHub pages site with an account. See attached link: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#:~:text=You%20can%20only%20create%20one,a%20personal%20account%2C%20are%20unlimited.

Comment: @FreddyNoNose ...but you can have an attached GH Pages *project* site for every single repo. The difference is that the user site has a URL like USER.github.io, and the project sites look like USER.github.io/PROJECT

Answer (score 0):

`gh-pages` pages is (or, rather, should be!) a **branch** not a repo. Your new new project should be in a new repo. Two repos can, of course, both have branches with the same name.

It sounds like you have set up the repos or the remotes for the repos incorrectly. Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75084210/edit) to add the URLs of the two repos and the results of running `git remote -v` in the local checkouts of the two repos.